# contains method in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

i know this is simple but im going crazy

```
public class CadastroPessoas {

Collection<Pessoa> lista;
Pessoa p;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CadastroPessoas p = new CadastroPessoas(); 
}

public CadastroPessoas() {
    lista = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p = new PessoaFisica();
        p.setNome(String.format("name %02d", i));
        p.setEmail(String.format("mail%02d@mail.com", i));
        p.setTelefone(String.format("122312%02d", i));

        if (!lista.contains(p)) {
            lista.add(p);
        }
    }
    for (Pessoa pessoa : lista) {
        System.out.println(pessoa.toString());
    }
} }
```

i want add various "PessoaFisica" to my collection but i need to check if this person exists, and with this code i just add the 1st one, what is wrong in my code

Comment: You mean only one is added after the whole loop? And do you have an `equals` method defined for `Pessoa`?

Comment: Also you should use `Set` instead of `(Array)List`. This type of collection prevents double entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) about the `contains` method of the `Collection interface`:

> Returns true if this collection contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this collection contains at
>   least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

```
o.equals(e)
```

Calls the non-overridden method of the class Object

I suggest you to override the method equals, for example

```
public class Pessoa
{
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Pessoa pessoa)
    {
        //You check if the fields are equal, if not, return false
        if(this.field != pessoa.field) return false;
        else if(this.field2 != pessoa.field2) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two inputs from my side here.

1)You are probably using the wrong collection interface for your purpose here. If you need to prevent duplicates you might be better off using a Set eg. HashSet or TreeSet.

2)As you have been told, you will need to override equals method in PessoaFisica and implement your own identity check, while you are at it do not forget to override hashCode() method. There is a contract between equals and hashCode. Two equal objects must have equal hashCodes.Most IDEs will generate this code for you, in idea go to Code->Generate->HashCode And Equals. It will ask you the fields to include and auto generate the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

from javadoc for the list interface :

```
boolean contains(Object o)
Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))
```

So, it looks like that you are not overriding the equals method in `PessoaFisica` class.